How to create a railing using geometry nodes?
I want to create something like this using geometry nodes to make it more flexible, currently im using array modifers.

Now I have a bezier curve and a setup to add posts in it, but the problem is I don't know how to add the railing part. Here's my current node setup.


There's a YT tutorial here. You can just leave out the chainlink section.

You just have to add a Curve to Mesh to your curve, with a Curve Circle as profile. Is that what you are looking for ?

Thanks for these comments, after following the tutorial alongside lutzi's comment, i have finnaly made it. Im new to geometry nodes, sorry for this question.

@Shinzef There is no reason to apologize for a question asked here (except perhaps if you are causing trouble). Your question is welcome, and if you have an answer yourself: even better! Then you are invited to write the answer yourself underneath, mark the answer as “Accepted answer” and then the question will appear as solved.
